# Running python LAMPP (linux) via apache

Tags: python, linux

I have a file: test.py
Permissions on this file are set to 777, I am attempting to run the following script:

```
#!/usr/lib/python2.7
print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print("test")
```

I receive the following error:

```
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message: 
End of script output before headers: test.py

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500
```

Python is installed:

```
$ python --version
>> Python 2.7.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem, you need to use the location of the python interpreter in the first line of the code which can be found by running the following script in the python interpreter (can be invoked by typing python into the terminal):

```
import sys; sys.executable;
```